# How to call a function each 2 min while webserver is running?

Tags: node.js, while-loop, webserver, localhost

my Problem is to call a function every two minutes WHILE a Webserver is running. So my Server starts like this:

```
app.listen(1309, function(){
    console.log("server is listening");
    doSomething();
});
```

And this is my function doSomething()

```
var doSomething = function(){
    while(true) {
        sleep.sleep(10);
        console.log("hello"); //the original function will be called here as soon as my code works :P
    }
};
```

So yes the function prints every 10 seconds (10 sec 
'cause testcase, don't want to wait 2 min atm) after starting my webserver but then it can't receive any get requests. (tested this with console.log)

I tried it without the function and it receives them. So I guess the while loop blocks the rest of the sever. How can I call this function every 2 minutes (or 10 sec) while the server is running and without missen any requests to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [setInteval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function:

```
const 2mins = 2 * 60 * 1000;
var doSomething = function() {
   setInterval(function() {
     console.log("hello");
   }, 2mins);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solves my problem, can you tell me why while isn't working ant whats the difference to setInterval ?

Comment: I think you use the [sleep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep) npm package. This package block execution of all JavaScript by halting Node.js' event loop. `setInterval` it's a native javascript function which runs related function after defined delay.